# Prototyping inheritance, setTimeout and clearTimeout

Tags: javascript

I'm confused.

I'm creating 2 objects that share the same prototype, but when the second one fires the `run()` method, I would expect it to stop the timeout which is set on the shared inherited object `timer` (`Foo.prototype.timer`).

If I change everything to use a global variable instead of `Foo.prototype.timer`, this works..

Why is it not clearing if both objects share the same `Foo.prototype.timer`?

```
function Foo(){
    // generate a random ID to show which object we're on
    this.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 2;
}

Foo.prototype = {
    run : function(){
        var that = this,
            count = 0;

        this.stop();
        function calc(){
            console.log(that.id);
            if( count++ < 20 )
                that.timer = setTimeout( calc, 100 );
        }

        that.timer = setTimeout( calc, 200 );
    },
    stop : function(){
       clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
}

// initiating

var foo = new Foo();
foo.run();

var bar = new Foo();
bar.run();
```

*(please copy and run this code in your console to see this issue.)*

Comment: Because `this.timer` is unique to each the instance...

Comment: how do I NOT make it unique? I thought that the unique things are only located at the Foo() itself

Comment: because you defined it in the prototype.. so the timers scope is the object. if you want all the objects to share the same timer, then you need to define it outside of the object

Comment: so I guess I'm not quite sure what is the purpose of the prototype if not sharing the same functions and objects that were prototyped across multiple instances...

Comment: I thought that if I explicitly define `Foo.prototype.timer = null`, then use `this.timer`, it will reference that prototyped one and not creating a new unique one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `that.timer`, you do not assign to the prototype - `that` is the instance, and so a new property will be created there. To set the property on the protoype, you will need to do it explicitly:

```
Foo.prototype.timer = setTimeout( calc, 200 ); // or, more verbose:
Object.getPrototypeOf(that).timer = setTimeout( calc, 200 );
```

Comment: @vsync: No, because `__proto__` is non-standard and not cross-browser-supported.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I NOT make it unique? I thought that the unique things are only
>   located at the Foo() itself

Anything you declare with `this` will be unique to the instance, even if declared inside the prototype. What get's shared is the prototype *not* the properties of each object.

Try with a module instead of a global variable, that way you can still make the variable private but shared:

```
var Foo = (function FooClass() {

  var timer;

  function Foo() {
    ...
  }

  Foo.prototype = {
    ...
  };

  return Foo;

}());
```

Comment: I can also use `this.__proto__.timer` and define it in prototype before.